# Drawing a figure from complex formula

Tags: python

I would like to draw a figure from the formula to the figure. The following code I wrote seems wrong. How should I fix it?

[image: FORMULA]

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot( [0])
plt.legend() 
x = np.linspace(0,120,121)
y = 2*20 / 500*("x")
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.xlim([0,120])
plt.ylim([0.0001,1])
plt.yscale("log")
plt.title("Graph Synchronization")
plt.xlabel("p")
plt.ylabel("lamda-min")
plt.show()
```

[image: FIGURE]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.   "Seems wrong" is not a problem description.

Comment: Maybe it had something to do with this statement where your `"x"` is a character : `y = 2*20 / 500*("x")` ?

Comment: Just posting a weird formula doesn't give much feedback. Maybe you can tell us what it represents as well as what each parameter it has means. Depending on the number of parameters it might be that 2D plot is not enough. And yes, doing arithmetics with a character doesn't make much sense.

Comment: So sorry about it. Let G1 , G2 be two graphs on n1 and n2 vertices, respectively, and let H be the graph obtained by adding k edges between G1 and G2.

Answer (score 0):

x = np.linspace ... is creating an x array

I suspect that you want to create a y array, and then plot y against x.

Using numpy, there is no need to do the python loop thing   for x_elem in x:, as numpy lets you work directly with arrays.

y = 2*20 / 500*x

will create a y array of the same length as x.

Then try the rest of your plot program.

Answer (score 0):

- You are dividing by an integer. Doing this performs floor division in python2. insert `from __future__ import division` on the first line of your program.
- also, let `y = 2*20 / 500*x`

I tested your code and these changes fixed everything

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is correct. but I would like to make a figure from ![1](http://www.fastpic.jp/images.php?file=6664105095.png) ,  ![2](http://www.fastpic.jp/images.php?file=6183962046.png) to the figure. What do I need? Let G1 , G2 be two graphs on n1 and n2 vertices, respectively, and let H be the graph obtained by adding k edges between G1 and G2.